# Does mmap need shm_open?

Tags: c, linux

I have a situation where I need to perform file IO but I'm sandboxed. So, I'm using shm_open with mmap, to return a file descriptor which I can happily read/write to/from in memory.

The problem I have is that a platform that I am porting to does not have shm_open. Does mmap require arg 5 to be a "file descriptor"? Or is there some other way I can use mmap without shm_open?

Thanks!

Comment: Does the data you write have to be persistent, i.e. it should be written to a disk? Do the mapped memory have to be shared between processes?

Comment: No, there is no need for persistent data. The data is passed from flash to the C process, then encoded. Once this is done, the data is then passed back to flash. No need to write to disk.

Comment: Yes I do need read/write. Sandboxed in the sense that I can't make any read/write's to disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `MAP_ANONYMOUS` flag to just map a piece of memory. This is basically the same as calling `malloc`, and no data you write will be saved as it's all in memory.